# Eclipse - Files are greyed out in project list and sometimes disappear?

Tags: eclipse, project

**Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:**

[image: Eclipse weirdness!]

If I navigate away from the **Controls** directory, the grey-ed out files will be temporarily hidden, and then I need to re-expand the folder for them to appear again...just for them to disappear.

I'm connected to Subversion with Subclipse.

Any ideas on this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have activated a Mylyn task and and Mylyn is tracking your active files.

[image: Focus on Active Task]

You should deselect the active task to return to normal mode.

[image]

Comment: How would I double check this?

Comment: Great! That fixed the disapearing issue, but some are still grey in color. Why is that?